# Android application to remove a segment from a video

Tags: android, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a Android application that can:

- remove a segment from a video: I shot a 15-minute video and I want to remove the segment from 11:30 to 12:17. Ideally I'd just have to specify the start timepoint and end timepoint, or use a slider like in [Microsoft Movie Maker](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Segments-of-a-Video-File-with-Microsoft-Movie-Maker-2012):

[image]

[image]

if possible:

- save the edited video as a new video
- free

Answer (score 1):

An app that should suit your needs is [Video Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.movisoftnew.videoeditor&hl=en). It is free, popular (10 million+ downloads), and highly-rated (4.2 stars on Google Play). It is also very easy to use and saves the new trimmed videos as separate files from the old videos. To trim videos, all you have to do is

1. Click on the scissors icon
2. Drag the two white sliders to select the part of the video you would like to trim
3. Click "Delete selected part"

It's really that simple!